# Permuting a vector efficiently in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, permutation

I want to make 1000 random permutations of a vector in matlab. I do it like this

```
% vector is A
num_A = length(A);

for i=1:1000
  n = randperm(num_A);
  A = A(n); % This is one permutation
end
```

This takes like 73 seconds. Is there any way to do it more efficiently?

Comment: Your code actually seems pretty straight-forward. `randperm` would be the way to go; I'm not sure that a better solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem 1 - Overwriting the original vector inside loop

Each time `A = A(n);` will overwrite `A`, the input vector, with a new permutation. This *might* be reasonable since anyway you don't need the *order* but all the elements in `A`. However, it's extremely inefficient because you have to re-write a million-element array in every iteration.

Solution: Store the permutation into a *new* variable -

```
B(ii, :) = A(n);
```

### Problem 2 - Using `i` as iterator

We at Stackoverflow are always telling serious Matlab users that using `i` and `j` as interators in loops is absolutely a bad idea. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17723167/3839249) to see why it makes your code slow, and check other answers in that page for why it's bad.

Solution - use `ii` instead of `i`.

### Problem 3 - Using unneccessary `for` loop

Actually you can avoid this `for` loop  at all since the iterations are not related to each other, and it will be faster if you allow Matlab do parallel computing.

Solution - use `arrayfun` to generate 1000 results at once.

### Final solution

Use `arrayfun` to generate `1000 x num_A` indices. I think (didn't confirm) it's faster than directly accessing `A`.

```
n = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) randperm(num_A), 1:1000', 'UniformOutput', false)');
```

Then store all 1000 permutations at once, into a new variable.

```
B = A(n);
```

---

I found [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27076-shuffle) pretty attractive. You can replace `randperm` with `Shuffle`. Example code -

```
B = Shuffle(repmat(A, 1000, 1), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = perms(num_A)
A = A(1:1000)
```

[Perms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) returns all the different permutations, just take the first 1000 permutations.

Comment: My vector is too big in the range of millions. So I cannot take all the perms at once

Comment: if that the case, your solution seems ok.. can't think any better solution.